# Flask routing parameter with wrong value

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using flask and wtforms. When a user clicks a submit button for the form, I want to pop up a message saying that the submission succeeded. For that I have a parameter for my flask route with a default value of False. When the user submits, I want it to be true, so when it re-renders the page, it knows to show the user the extra bit saying "Success". However the parameter always seems to be false. My python looks like,

```
@app.route('/myPage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def myPage(success=False):
    print success

    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print "did validate"
        return redirect(url_for('myPage', success=True))

    return render_template('/MyPage.html', form=form, success=success)
```

And my html looks like,

```
...
{% if success %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> User added
    </div>
{% endif %}
...
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('register', success=True) }}">
...
```

In both my python and html redirects, I try setting success to be true, but no combination of those seem to work. When I "print success", it always says that it is false. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask binds method parameters to route arguments if they a part of the route. See [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#url-route-registrations]).

Try:

```
@app.route('/mypage/<int:success>', defaults={'success': 0})
def my_page(success):
   ...
```

This would cause `url_for` to build a URL like `/mypage/1` or `/mypage/True`, which is probably not what you want.

If you want to use a querystring parameter, you should manually get it from the request:

```
@app.route('/mypage/')
def my_page():
  success = request.args.get('success', False)
  ...
```

`url_for('my_page', success=True)` would now generate something like `/mypage/?success=True` because:

> Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments.

(from the [`url_for` docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for))

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the "success = request.args.get('success', False)" method, and it works like a charm.